# ZeroMq Router silently drops messages

Tags: messaging, zeromq, jeromq

I have a server (ROUTER  socket) which binds and allows a single client (DEALER socket) to connect to it. The server then starts to send data.

Ideally, I would like to know when the router reaches its hwm setting and starts to drop messages. I have set the ZMQ_ROUTER_MANDATORY to 1 on the router but that doesn't help either. The router continues to report that the messages are sent even though I  deliberatly didn't start the client (isAlive = false, so there is nothing to pull those meesages on the other end).

Am I doing something wrong or is the HWM setting simply unreliable on a ROUTER socket?

I am using jeromq version 0.3.1 with jdk 1.6.0_32 on Windows 7 64-bit

Thanks

```
public final class SenderSocket implements Runnable{

    private final int total;
    private final int sentHwm;
    private final String address;
    private final Socket sendSocket;
    private final ExecutorService executor;

    private final static String NAME        = SenderSocket.class.getSimpleName( );
    private final static Logger LOGGER      = LoggerFactory.getLogger( NAME );


    public SenderSocket( ZContext context, String address, int sentHwm, int total ){
        this.address        = address;
        this.total          = total;
        this.sentHwm        = sentHwm;
        this.sendSocket     = context.createSocket( ZMQ.ROUTER );
        this.executor       = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor( );
    }


    public void init( ){

        sendSocket.setSndHWM( sentHwm );
        sendSocket.setRouterMandatory( true );
        sendSocket.bind( address );

        executor.execute( this );
        LOGGER.info("ROUTER configured with HWM {} bound to {}.", sentHwm, address );

    }



    @Override
    public void run( ){         

        for( int i =0; i <total; i++ ){      

            try{

                String item     = new StringBuilder(8).append(i).toString();
                boolean result  = sendSocket.send( item );

                LOGGER.info("SENT>> [{}] [{}]", result, item );

            }catch( ZMQException zmqEx ){

                int errorCode = zmqEx.getErrorCode();

                if( ZError.EHOSTUNREACH == errorCode ){
                    LOGGER.warn("Attempted to send message to but dealer is DOWN!");
                }

                if( ZMQ.Error.ETERM.getCode() == errorCode ){
                    LOGGER.error("Received error code [{}], terminating.");
                    stop();
                }

                LOGGER.error("ZMQException while sending message.", zmqEx);

            }catch( Exception ex ){
                LOGGER.error("Exception while sending message.", ex );
            }

        }

        stop();

    }


    public void stop( ){
        sendSocket.setLinger( 0 );
    }


}
```

//CLIENT

```
    public class ReceiverSocket implements Runnable{

        private final int hwm;
        private final String address;
        private final Socket recvSocket;
        private final ExecutorService executor;

        private volatile boolean isAlive;

        private final static String NAME        = ReceiverSocket.class.getSimpleName( );
        private final static Logger LOGGER      = LoggerFactory.getLogger( NAME );


        public ReceiverSocket( ZContext context, String address, int hwm ){
            this.address        = address;
            this.hwm            = hwm;
            this.recvSocket     = context.createSocket( ZMQ.DEALER );
            this.executor       = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor( );
        }


        public void init( ){

            this.isAlive = false;

            recvSocket.setRcvHWM( hwm );
            recvSocket.connect( address );
            executor.execute( this );

            LOGGER.info("DEALER configured with HWM {} connected to {}.", hwm, address );

        }



        @Override
        public void run( ){         

            Poller poller       = new Poller( 1 );
            poller.register( recvSocket, Poller.POLLIN );

            while(  isAlive ){      

                try{

                    int pollCount       = poller.poll( );

                    if( pollCount == NEGATIVE_ONE ){
                        LOGGER.warn("ERROR! Was the thread interrupted?", pollCount );
                        isAlive = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    if( poller.pollin( ZERO ) ){
                        String data = recvSocket.recvStr( );
                        LOGGER.info("RECVD >> {} {}", data, NEWLINE );
                    }

                }catch( Exception e ){
                    LOGGER.error("Exception while receving message.", e);
                }

            }

        }


        public void stop( ){
            recvSocket.setLinger( 0 );
            LOGGER.info("{} Stopped!", NAME );
        }
}
```

//MAIN

```
public static void main( String[ ] args ) throws InterruptedException{

        int recvHwm          = 5;
        int sentHwm          = 5;
        int totalSent        = 5000;
        String address       = "tcp://*:20000";
        ZContext context     = new ZContext( 1 );

        ReceiverSocket recvr = new ReceiverSocket( context, address, recvHwm );
        SenderSocket sender  = new SenderSocket( context, address, sentHwm, totalSent );

        recvr.init();
        Thread.sleep( 1000 );

        sender.init();

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Router mandatory and high water mark have nothing to do with each other.

> I have set the ZMQ_ROUTER_MANDATORY to 1 on the router but that
>   doesn't help either. The router continues to report that the messages
>   are sent even though I deliberatly didn't start the client

Router won't raise an exception even if no peers are connected to it unless you address the message for a specific client id.

```
//#1 no exception raised here, message dropped silently
rtr.setRouterMandatory(true)
rtr.bind("tcp://*:20000")
rtr.send("omg!")

//#2 exception raised here
rtr.setRouterMandatory(true)
rtr.bind("tcp://*:20000")
rtr.sendMore("client1")
rtr.sendMore("")
rtr.send("omg!")
```

Code sample #2 throws exception because you're telling router to send "omg" to a peer with identity `client1`. Router sockets track all connections by assigning a random identity to each connected peer. If the router has no connection for `client1`, or, if `client1` previously disconnected, router will raise an exception in both cases.

You can assign an identity on the client to override the routers random identity assignment:

```
client.setIdentity("client1".getBytes())
client.connect("tcp://*:20000")
```

The above code stops the router socket from throwing an exception in sample #2

I suggest reading up on [this](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php%3achapter3#Identities-and-Addresses), it explains message addressing and enveloping; understanding how it works is essential to using router sockets.

Comment: Thanks Raffian, after setting the identity (can't believe I had forgotten) I do get an exception if the peer is not connected. Is there a way to find out if ROUTER is dropping messages if its send HWM has been reached? (assuming DEALER is connected but not pulling messages at all).

Comment: The functionality to detect when ROUTER exceeds HWM does not exist, see this: http://grokbase.com/t/zeromq/zeromq-dev/119t6vb1yq/logging-hwm-events

Comment: Thanks again. I just discovered in 0.3.1 that ROUTER will actually block if setRouterMandatory(true) is set and hwm has been reached. Without the setting, it works as documented and drops messages.

Comment: That's interesting, so they're connected in that regard; can you post the link with that info? thx

Comment: Here is the posting which made me attempt the test. http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.zeromq.devel/18624

Comment: Oh, my bad, lol, I thought you were referring to something in the docs..rough week!

Comment: :) No worries, thanks for all your help and have a good weekend.

Answer (score 0):

in python, this make the router raise zmq.Again on such scenarios:

```
    self.context = zmq.Context()
    self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)

    # make sure router doesn't just drop unroutable message
    self.socket.setsockopt(zmq.ROUTER_MANDATORY, 1)

    # make sure when there is unroutable message to raise exception after timeout
    timeout_sec = 2.5
    timeout_milisec = int(timeout_sec * 1000)
    self.socket.setsockopt(zmq.SNDTIMEO, timeout_milisec)
```

see http://grokbase.com/t/zeromq/zeromq-dev/12aje3ya9t/zmq-router-mandatory-was-zmq-router-behavior